# mv files into folders based on numbering in names

Tags: files, rename, mv, numbering

I have 30 folders:

```
s-01
s-02
...
s-30
```

And, I have 30 files:

```
txtFile-001
txtFile-002
...
txtFile-030
```

How can I perform the following operation in one shot

```
mv txtFile-001 s-01/txtFile
mv txtFile-002 s-02/txtFile
...
mv txtFile-030 s-30/txtFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a for loop:

```
for i in $(seq -w 1 30); do mv -v "txtFile-0${i}" "s-${i}/txtFile"; done
```

This runs trough `01` to `30` and calls for every number the `mv` command, where `$i` contains the number.

**Edit:** without `seq` it would loop like:

```
for i in {01..30}; do mv -v "txtFile-0${i}" "s-${i}/txtFile"; done
```

Comment: Apologies, I updated the question, since the txtFiles have a different way of numbering than folders. It would help if you can update your answer accordingly.

Comment: @WanderingMind Since it's only that leading `0` in the filename, just add it in the `mv` command or see my updated answer

Comment: It works for i>=10, but fails for i<10. I think it needs a conditional statement

Comment: Does you `seq` accept the `-w` flag? You can also use the second statement in my updated answer

Comment: Yes my seq accepts -w command and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In one shot?

```
prename 's!txtFile-0(..)$!s-$1/txtFile!' txtFile*
```

This uses a Regular Expression to split off the trailing two digits of txtFile-0nn and use it as the directory suffix.